# How to access value inside promise?

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I'm trying to learn to use promise.
In this case i want to make a web **scraper** . I'm using `request-promise` inside this code.

Actually the **scraper** is working fine. I have missunderstand how to use the return value inside `then()`. I am also have googled it but no luck and still get stuck. Here is my code.

```
    let categories = scraper.getCategories(promoUrl);
    categories.then(function (val) {
        let promoPerCategory = [];
        for (let i = 0, len = val.length; i < len; i++) {
            let json = {
                category: val[i].category,
                url: val[i].url,
                promo: []
            }

            scraper.getPromoPerCategories(val[i].url)
            .then(function (allPromo) {
                for (let j = 0, lenResult = allPromo.length; j < lenResult; j++) {
                    json.promo.push({
                        imageUrl: allPromo[j].imageUrl,
                        merchantName: allPromo[j].merchantName,
                        promoTitle: allPromo[j].promoTitle,
                        validUntil: allPromo[j].validUntil,
                        promoUrl: allPromo[j].promoUrl
                    });

                    console.log(json.promo[j]);
                }
                
            })
            promoPerCategory.push(json);
        }

        result.send({ "promoPerCategory": promoPerCategory });
    })
```

the `then()` inside function `getPromoPerCategories` is working fine, i print out the value using `console.log(json.promo[j])`

But the problem is i want to put array from `json.promo[j]` into array `promoPerCategory` so that i can return it using `result.send({ "promoPerCategory": promoPerCategory })`

Can you please help me to do the right way? any help will be very appreciated.

Result is now like this

```
{"promoPerCategory":   [{"category":"Fashion","url":"https://","promo":[]}
```

object `promo` is empty array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first problem is that `result.send` is not waiting for the `getPromoPerCategories` result. To make that happen, `result.send` needs to be in a callback of the `getPromoPerCategories` promise. It also looks like you want to wait for all of your results to come back before calling `result.send`, so you should use `Promise.all` and wait on all of the `getPromoPerCategories` promises. For example:

```
categories.then(function (val) {
    let promoPerCategory = [],
        promoPerCategoryPromises = [];
    for (let i = 0, len = val.length; i < len; i++) {
        let json = {
            category: val[i].category,
            url: val[i].url,
            promo: []
        }

        var promise = scrapper.getPromoPerCategories(val[i].url)
        .then(function (allPromo) {
            for (let j = 0, lenResult = allPromo.length; j < lenResult; j++) {
                json.promo.push({
                    imageUrl: allPromo[j].imageUrl,
                    merchantName: allPromo[j].merchantName,
                    promoTitle: allPromo[j].promoTitle,
                    validUntil: allPromo[j].validUntil,
                    promoUrl: allPromo[j].promoUrl
                });
                console.log(json.promo[j]);
            }
            promoPerCategory.push(json);
        });

        promoPerCategoryPromises.push(promise);
    }
    Promise.all(promoPerCategoryPromises).then(function() {
      result.send({ "promoPerCategory": promoPerCategory });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [];

scrapper.getPromoPerCategories(val[i].url)
.then(function() {
  data.push({'foo': 'bar'});
});

result.send(data);
```

Or you can just `result.send()` inside the promise chain.

```
.then(function() {
  var data = [];
  data.push({'foo': 'bar'});
  result.send(data);
});
```

Comment: I believe in your first example it will send an empty array. `result.send` will be called before the promise is resolved. Second example will work though.

Comment: yes, it is and i dont know how to solve it. Alejandro answer is perfect. Thank you for your answer too Sir.